# Access to HTML Elements on Windows Phone APP using C#

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8

I wrote a mobile app for Windows Mobile 8 which sends Ajax request to retrieve some data from web.

My Mobile App stores variables on HTML5 LocalStorage and I need to access thoes values to update my LIVE-TILE Content.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: show us what have you done for. Helps other to get to the point quickly and provide you a better option .. refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using WebBrowser control, you can access to html element through javascript functions.
Just create javascript function in your html page and invoke it from C# code, for example:

```
function test(foo){
alert(foo);
}

private void TestButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("test", 1234);
}
```

Comment: I have used WebClient Method to Retrieve HTML Data on Codebehind but still looking for a method if is possible to implement.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you need to do?